# groovy use var when other var is not defined

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have two variables in my script.

```
var1 = foo
var2 = (defined outside of the script)
```

What I need is something that defines var2 as var1 when var2 is not defined.

So lets say var2 is not defined, because the user didn't define it, then it should be this

```
var2 = var1
```

How can I do this?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside the groovy script you can do this:

```
if(!this.getBinding().hasVariable('var2'))this.getBinding().setVariable('var2',var1)
println "var1 = ${var1}"
println "var2 = ${var2}"
```

or simplified option:

```
if(!binding.hasVariable('var2')) binding.var2 = var1
```

Comment: Do you get the same result if you replace `if(!this.getBinding().hasVariable('var2'))this.getBinding().setVariable('var2',var1)` with `if(!binding.hasVariable('var2')) binding.var2 = var1`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, you are right. i just preffer to share exact accessor/names to be clear.  it's possible to simplify )

Comment: "you are right" - I wasn't making a claim.  I was asking you if they behaved the same.  Thanks.

Comment: yes, the result is the same.